# Loading different sized background images based on browser width using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a page that I would like to have different images load as the background based on the width of the display port. I understand how to do it with the picture tag and the srcset tags for regular images but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it when working with the background image of a tag? 
The css that I am currently using is

```
body{
background-image:url(/Content/Images/CloudGradient_480.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use media queries, but give them both an upper and a lower limit. Otherwise all the images are going to be loaded, even if only one is displayed. This way, only one image will be loaded, which saves bandwidth and loading time:

```
body {
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background-image:url(/Content/Images/CloudGradient_800.jpg);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background-image:url(/Content/Images/CloudGradient_1200.jpg);
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    background-image:url(/Content/Images/CloudGradient_2000.jpg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use media query

For example:

```
body{
    background-image:url(/Content/Images/CloudGradient_1280.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}

@media max-width: 500px {
    body {
        background-image:url(/Content/Images/CloudGradient_480.jpg);
    }
}
@media max-width: 700px {
    body {
        background-image:url(/Content/Images/CloudGradient_680.jpg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it using `CSS media queries`, you would have different background image for different screen or port sizes.